# how we should design communication between different internal Microservices

Tags: java, spring, rest, architecture, microservices

I am new to Microservices. I am currently developing an application using Microservices and using both synchronous and asynchronous communication.

Recently I have read many articles saying that you shouldn't use synchronous(HTTP) communication and should only use asynchronous(message broker). A few have mentioned - If the Microservices are communicating via REST, then you still have, in effect, a monolithic application.

Consider a scenario where we have 2 Microservices (MS) :

1. **CurrencyConversion** MS - We will pass input to this MS as we want to convert $100 to INR. CurrencyConversion MS will execute a GET call to CurrencyExchange MS to get exchange rate for $ to INR.
2. **CurrencyExchange** MS - We will pass input to this MS as $ to INR and CurrencyExchange MS will return the exchange rate as 75 i.e. $1 = 75 INR.

In such cases, CurrencyConversion can't work independently and if CurrencyExchange is failing, CurrencyConversion is also going to fail.

So my first question is - Is synchronous communication between services an anti-pattern in Microservices?

The second question is - If synchronous communication is not a preferred way then what is the **best way to design communication between different internal services** where one service is going to **execute a GET call to get some dependent data** for example the scenario I have mentioned above.

How do we overcome this without using synchronous communication?

Comment: You should ask this Q in [SoftwareEngineering stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Based on the use-case you need to do sync[blocked] or async call, there is no silver bullet. For the example you gave, why do you think `sync` communication between 2 services will not work or scale ?

Comment: Thank you Anand for your time. In our application, we are using sync communication but I am confused after reading these many articles that if we are designing communication between services properly or we should change/rectify our approach.

Comment: Synchronous communication between services IS NOT an anti-pattern in Microservices. In general I wouldn't take seriously articles that trying to generalize architecture decisions and provide rules like "it is always should be...". In architecture there is no "always", there is "it depends". Everything is a trade-off, and there are pros & cons for both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous communication between services is not an anti-pattern in Microservices. But it's important to choose a appropriate communication style depending on the specified quality requirements. [Microservices.io](https://microservices.io) describes some communication patterns with pros & cons, tradeoffs and examples.

> In such cases, CurrencyConversion can't work independently and if CurrencyExchange is failing, CurrencyConversion is also going to fail.

In your example the two MS are highly coupled cause they need to work together in a synchronous transaction to answer the user request. Assuming that the user wants a response within a specific time interval (lets say 50ms), synchronous communication seems appropriate. Cascading errors can be counteracted with resilience patterns (circuit breaker, bulk head, etc.). In my opinion the example functionality should get deployed in just one MS (Currency-Service). The two described operations and the underlaying domain model seem highly cohesive. That's a strong signal you should not split the functionality into multiple MS. Communication problems solved :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and valuable input. I wanted to understand if synchronous communication is allowed in microservices architecture or not because I saw many articles where they have emphasized not using synchronous communication at all.  

Now I understand that synchronous communication is not an anti-pattern and we should try to build loosely coupled services and use async communication where ever possible but when one service needs an immediate response from the next service, we could use sync communication as well. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. :D

Comment: Glad that helped you :) Yes, your understanding ist correct :) A major goal of Microservice Architectures is that you want to be able to deploy every MS independently. To achieve this its recommended to design loosely coupled MS. Otherwise, a so-called "distributed monolith" could emerge and that's definitely an Anti-Pattern ;) A popular alternative approach is data duplication. A MS publishes its shared data asynchronously. Other MS can persist duplicates of this data so they don't need to call each other to aggregate data. This approach comes from the ideas and practices of DDD.

Answer (score 3):

When you are on a microservices project, it is very frequent that microservices need other microservices. As you said, there are several ways to communicate between them: synchronously or asynchronously.

For my part, I think that there is no good or bad choice between synchronous and asynchronous, what you need to do is to choose what best meets your needs.

In the case you mention, I would personally choose a synchronous HTTP call simply because if you made an asynchronous call, it would be more difficult to know if your MS has received the request and especially when it will answer it. This could force you to block the call from your client for a while because he is calling you synchronously in HTTP on a REST resource.

However, if your client does not expect an immediate response to his call, you can very well start with an asynchronous call and provide a notification system to inform your client that the response to his request is ready.

In any case, synchronous calls between microservices should not be considered as anti-patterns. Synchronous and asynchronous calls each meet different needs, so you have to choose which one is more appropriate in your case.

Finally, whether you do synchronous or asynchronous, there are still several ways to do it. Here is a link that explains, I think, quite well the different possibilities for these two solutions : https://dzone.com/articles/patterns-for-microservices-sync-vs-async

Comment: Thank you for your time and valuable input.